# Why am I getting a KeyError when trying to use an Enum as a dictionary key in another file?

Tags: python

I have two files, `enum_test.py` and `print_test_file.py`. I defined an Enum class in `enum_test.py` and created a dictionary using members of that Enum class as keys. When I tried to use that dictionary in `print_test_file.py` I got a key error.

Here is the code for `enum_test.py`:

```
from enum import Enum
import print_test_file

class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

def main():
    enumDict = dict()
    enumDict[MyEnum.A] = 'abcd'
    enumDict[MyEnum.B] = 'efgh'

    print(enumDict[MyEnum.A])
    print_test_file.print_test(enumDict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and here is the code from `print_test_file.py`

```
import enum_test

def print_test(enumDict):
    print(enumDict[enum_test.MyEnum.A])
```

I was expecting that running `enum_test` would produce the following output:

```
abcd
abcd
```

but instead it only prints the first `abcd` and then throws `KeyError: <MyEnum.A: 1>`

How can I use the dictionary I created in `enum_test.py` from `print_test_file.py`?

Comment: Can you provide the traceback of your error, including the line number where this occurs?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus If you remove the `Enum`, both of the values are just `1`, and any two instances of `1` are equal. If you leave it in, both of the values are enum constants, and no two enum constants are ever equal (except for cases like `IntEnum`, or when you customize the class manually). But that doesn’t mean there’s a bug in Enum. The bug is that he has two separate classes, because he has two separate module objects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is exactly why you should never `import` the same module that you're running as a script. You end up with two completely independent module objects, `enum_test` and `__main__`, with their own completely independent global namespaces, containing separate objects that were constructed from the same code.

`__main__.main()` builds a dict, and fills it with `__main__.MyEnum` keys.

`print_test_file.print_test` takes that dict as a parameter. But then it tries to search it using `enum_test.MyEnum.A`. And that key does not exist in that dict. So you get a `KeyError`.

---

Your modules *also* have circular dependencies, which is obscured by this problem. I'm pretty sure you'd actually get away with the circular dependencies in this case if nothing else was wrong, but it's still confusing to have to think through the order of how top-level module code gets executed, so it's better to avoid them.

---

The easy way to fix both problems at once is to move the shared code into a separate shared module, which both your script and your test module can import.

```
# enum_test.py
from my_enum import MyEnum
import print_test_file

def main():
    enumDict = dict()
    enumDict[MyEnum.A] = 'abcd'
    enumDict[MyEnum.B] = 'efgh'

    print(enumDict[MyEnum.A])
    print_test_file.print_test(enumDict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

```
# print_test_file.py
import my_enum

def print_test(enumDict):
    print(enumDict[my_enum.MyEnum.A])
```

---

```
# my_enum.py
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

Now, there's no module that imports the script, and no module that imports the module that imports it. (In technical terms, instead of a graph with cycles in it, you just have a tree, with the script at the root.)

---

Every few years, someone suggests changing Python to eliminate this problem, but there really is no good answer. They could make it an error to import the same module being run as a script, but that could break some uncommon but important use cases (like `multiprocessing`). Or they could make it “just work” by doing an implicit `sys.modules['enum_test'] = sys.modules['__main__']` somewhere—but there really is no “somewhere” that wouldn’t turn the circular dependency in your code (and almost every other example of this problem) from mostly harmless to a serious bug.

(By the way, I vaguely remember that in one of the discussions, one of the core devs who’s also a teacher mentioned that very few of his students ever run into this problem, but the ones who do tend to end up near the top of the class, so at least you have that to feel good about.)

Comment: Sir, I create print(id(MyEnum)) in enum_test.py and print(id(enum_test.MyEnum)) in print_test_file.py and the id are different, does it suggest that they are different instances?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus Yes. (They’re classes, so it’s a _bit_ confusing to call them instances, but it’s not incorrect—classes are just instances of their metaclasses.)

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus And the _reason_ they’re different instances is that the same source code, the code in `enum_test.py`, is being run twice, once to create the module `__main__` to run as the script, and once to create the module `enum_test` that gets imported by `print_test_file`. That’s hard to get a handle on, but once you do, everything else is obvious. It’s just like if you copied and pasted the same class definition twice in a row—you’d get two separate classes.

Comment: Yes, now I have a better understadning, even I delete Enum, they are still different instances, but because the key '1' is universal, so it works, I changed my answer content. Thanks for teaching!

Comment: I encountered this, but in my case, for some reason only known to the runtime, after setting the enum object on a class member it was implicitly converted to a (val,) tuple (Python 3.8). That looks a lot like bug to me.

Comment: I encountered the same problem with a simpler situation that doesn't import the script to the original file. I think the problem is not what you describe, but your solution solves it regardless.

In my situation, I have three modules: 
Module1: define an enum (E) and a dict (D) with enum values as its keys.
Module2: import the dict and write a accessor funciton (F): "def F(key): return D[key]"
Module 3: import E from Module1 and F from Module 2, and call F(E.<someValue>)

this fails with a KeyError too. It seems the solution is to split the enum and the dict to different modules. why ?